# Call Perl function on a server

Tags: android, perl

I wanna try to run Perl Scripts on a Windows Web Server, which should be no problem. Furthermore I have an Android App, which passes some values to the Perl scripts (there's no other way for me; I have to use them). Finally the calculated values should be sent back to the Android App.

I have nearly no experience with Perl, so I have a few questions:
- What's the best way to call Perl functions from an Android App? 
- How do I send back the values?

I don't want to get the full source code, jusrt some keywords and/or a link to a page where I can read on. Right now I just have no idea to do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, is there any reason for using Perl?

In the end it does not matter which technology you're going to use, but I would suggest web service created in Perl/PHP/Python/Ruby running under Apache/Nginx web server and just send a HTTP Request through android and receive the values.

P.S.: As transferring I would suggest as JSON rather than XMLs

Is this helpful for you? :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 

I have to use Perl because I have to extend/modify an already existing program oen of my coworkers wrote. There's just one problem: I have nearly no idea about Perl so I have to learn Perl basics first and then I have to read into the whole transfering thing. 

The Android App will send some values to the server. With this parameters a text file will be created which will be downloaded back to the phone. So that's the problem right now. :)

Comment: Alrighty, well I hope I helped you by answering the question in really not specific way, because there are more ways to achieve this, but better to try them all yourself :)